# react native flux router with react-native-camera

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux, react-native-camera

I'm trying to preview the image I get in the next scene but the transition doesn't happen when I click on the camera button.

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

export default class PageTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
         <Camera ref={(cam) => { this.camera = cam; }}
            style={styles.preview}
            aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
                <Text style={styles.capture} 
                      onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}> 
                         <Icon name="ios-camera"/>
                </Text>
         </Camera>
      </View>
    )
 }

 takePicture() {
     this.camera.capture()
       .then((data) => {Actions.previewimg});
 }
}
```

Comment: How do you define Scenes ?

Comment: @AhmedAli what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are not calling the router transition properly. `Actions` holds a function that makes a transition to a certain screen, with the same name given in the `key` prop of each `<Scene>`. These are functions, and so you have to call them. Change your code to do:

```
takePicture() {
     this.camera.capture()
       .then((data) => {Actions.previewimg()});
}
```

Also, the data will not be passed to the next screen unless you explicitely do so. So your code should look like this:

```
takePicture() {
     this.camera.capture()
       .then((data) => {Actions.previewimg({data: data}});
}
```

And then your `previewimg` scene will have an extra prop called `data` that will hold your image.

Comment: no didn't get anything on the log it just crashes now when I click the button :/

Comment: It looks like the native code of the component has not been properly included on the code. You might want to check that. Also, have you checked the native app logs (adb logcat, for example)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by martinarroyo is the correct way to do it. You have to call it properly and to pass the data you have to pass it as parameters.

App crashes mostly on Android devices. You have to check your native java code and insert it properly along with the **permissions** (many people forget the permissions). And sometimes due to crashing too often your camera in general stops working. So, give it some time and open your default camera app of your device then open your app again. It will work.